# Smart app banner only appear if app already installed

Tags: android, jquery, ios, smartbanner

I am using `Jquery.smartbanner` plugin for promotion my app when some one try to open my site in mobile.

Its work fine if my app already installed.

I want to display app banner if app isn't installed in my mobile and if app already installed than display open button instead of install.

Thank In Advance.

Comment: I would recommend using [native app banner](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/increasing-engagement-with-app-install-banners-in-chrome-for-android) instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use smart banner:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Or you can try to set a timout:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startMyApp()
{
  document.location = 'MyAppScheme://';
  setTimeout( function()
  {
      if( confirm( 'You don't have Your App installed, do you want to go download it?'))
      {
        document.location = 'http://itunes.apple.com/MyApp';
      }
  }, 200);
 }
</script>
```